# is there something wrong with my xml file?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

is there something wrong with the xml i created? is there any way i can optimize or improve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <countries>
        <country>
            <countryname>Philippines</countryname>
            <subsidiaries>
                <subsidiary>
                    <name>Sartorius Philippines Inc.</name>
                <address>Unit 20-A The World Centre Building, 330 Senator Gil Puyat Avenue Makati 1209 City Philippines, Philippines</address>
                <phone>+63.2.8640.929</phone>
                <fax>+63.28640.932</fax>
                <email>enquiry.philippines@sartorius.com</email>
                <website>http://www.sartorius-mechatronics.com.ph</website>
            </subsidiary>
        </subsidiaries>
    </country>
<country>
        <countryname>Denmark</countryname>
        <subsidiaries>
            <subsidiary>
                <name>Sartorius Stedim Nordic A|S</name>
                <address>stedim Hoerskaetten 6d 2630 Taastrup, Denmark</address>
                <phone>+45.7023.4400</phone>
                <fax>+45.4630.4030</fax>
                <email>ne.customersupport@sartorius.com</email>
                <website></website>
            </subsidiary>
            <subsidiary>
                <name>Sartorius Nordic A|S</name>
                <address>Hoerskaetten 6D 2630 Taastrup, Denmark</address>
                <phone>+45.7023.4400</phone>
                <fax>+45.4630.4030</fax>
                <email>ne.customersupport@sartorius.com</email>
                <website></website>
            </subsidiary>
        </subsidiaries>
    </country>
</countries>
```

im just new at creating xml, i have no idea if my xml is good or not, i need your advice. thanks!

Comment: Does it do what you need it to do? If so, it's good. There's no right or wrong way in creating xml structure as long as it serves its purpose.

Comment: what happened did you failed to parse this xml?

Comment: actually when i parsed it, it was ok, i'm just having a hard time displaying the value of the <name> element under "Denmark" as you can see i have two <subsidiary> in one <country>

Comment: you might need to enclose nodes with html entities like email ids to wrap in a CDATA section.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is valid and well formed, as validated by http://validator.w3.org/

Not 100% here, but i think you write `<website></website>` as `<website />` if you wanted to..